# Calling a secured WebService from jQuery safely

Tags: jquery, .net, ajax, security

I have a WebService which has several calls which are only available to members of the site. I want to build a pure html/jQuery mobile app which can call into this service make requests and download information.

My initial plan was to put the users' username and password in the auth header but I'm worried  about exposing them to any traffic sniffers. I can obviously create a session key so after the initial authentication they call in with a token but this may be vulnerable to session stealing.

My current plan is:

- Implement a Login call, this will return a token which will expire after a designated time
- The JS calls in with this token (thereby reducing the number of times the password is sent).
- The user makes their calls
- The token is compared against the user's IP address.
- The user logs out, this ends the session and removes the key early to reduce risk

Another thought was to encrypt the password as I send it. Is it possible/sensible to do public/private key encryption in JS based on the .NET RSACryptoServiceProvider implementation?

What is the best approach to handle authentication, ideally without purchasing an SSL certificate (the data itself is not particularly sensitive). ?

Comment: "without purchasing an SSL certificate" would you consider getting a free SSL certificate?

Comment: @guest at the moment I'm considering all the options. Cost is a factor so I'd rather simply using SSL if possible

Comment: If you're only worried about login/password sniffing, just send them hashed, using SHA1 function. If you want to keep whole connection and all calls (Client <-> WebService) to be safely encrypted, you'll have to use an encryption protocol - the Internet is full of comparisons and implementations of many different kinds.

Comment: And if you really want to prevent all man-in-the-middle attacks (which is highly recommended, as it is a mobile app), you _really_ should use SSL. You should secure the transport layer of your connection.

Comment: @KamilT SSL could well be the best method. For the sake of the cost it's much safer. WRT hashing if the app sends the password hashed then assuming we store a hashed version how can you compare to correct value?

Comment: @Liath you store the hashed login and password in your database (you may keep the `unhashed` version of login too, for maintenance reasons). Then, in your app, you just generate the hashed version of login and password (there are loads of jQuery libs for SHA1) and send them to Web Service. In WS, you only compare hashed values - if they're identical, the password and login matches, if not - it's 'incorrect login / password'. That way, even if someone sniffs your WS call, they only have useless hash, not the plaintext login/password, which may take years to break.

Comment: @Liath - you should also add some 'salt' to your login and password hashes (both stored in DB and hashed directly in your app). This means, that, f.e., instead of hashing 'MyPass1234asdf', you add some extra data at the beginning, middle and the end, so you get for example : 'a1s2d3MyPass128454534asdfpoiuyt'. That way, even if someone breaks the hash, he still won't have the 'perfect', complete data.

Comment: @KamilT but surely that exposes your salt/hash rules to anyone who looks at the JS?

Comment: @Liath And althought hashing is quite a good way, it is still TONS better to use SSL - as I said, it secures the whole transport layer, not only login / password / session key, but also ALL your Web Service connection.

Comment: @KamilT thanks for your suggestions - worth posting as an answer?

Comment: @Liath About the salt - my bad, forgot that's it's all in pure jQuery...

Comment: @Liath Posted an answer, hope it helps ;)

Comment: SSL is the **only** solution to this problem. With Client side encryption you have to expose you key, salt and encryption algorithm to the client (and therefore anyone in between) making it very simple to unencrypt your data on the wire rendering the encryption useless.

Comment: *Strongly* agree with @Liam: your question is basically "now that I've ruled out the only actual solution to my problem, how can I solve my problem?" You can't, so I wouldn't even bother wasting your time. Either the data is sufficiently sensitive to warrant proper security precautions, or it isn't in which case don't spend your own valuable time faux-securing the system when you could be adding other features (or napping in a hammock).

Comment: @dlev if that's your answer would you mind posting it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apart from obvious reasons why SSL is highly recommended, and you should definitely use it if it's possible, you can consider rising your security by hashing your login and password.

Hashes work in a way that is very difficult to break - hashes of very similar strings are completely different, even if you only change one char. See that:

```
Login: "jacek", SHA1: "9749d1492af3d43f9c09e04c5c43f27bb909af51"
Login: "Jacek", SHA1: "46c676716f0e9aa86545c034d0e22a114d7cd488"
```

This shows that you need an EXACT password (or it's hash collisions, which are difficult to compute) to 'break' the hash, and a 'simmilar' one is completely useless.

Your implementation may go like that:
When you create a user (f.e. registration moment), you compute hash of login and password. After that, in DB you will have:

```
Login  | HashedLogin                              | HashedPassword 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
jacek  | 9749d1492af3d43f9c09e04c5c43f27bb909af51 | e4e088f4eaa96db85e11ba491a189f96f2e11793
```

(You may keep an unhashed login for debugging / maintanence purposes only.)

After that, before you conect to Web Service in your app, you do exactly the same, but in jQuery:

```
var _HashedLogin = Sha1_Hash($("#login").text());
var _HashedPassword = Sha1_Hash($("#password").text());
```

There are lots of third-party SHA1 libs, use any of them ;)

Then, when you send info to your webservice, send the hashed values only.
Even if someone sniffs your ajax call, he will only get something like:

```
"UserInfo":
{
    "login" : "9749d1492af3d43f9c09e04c5c43f27bb909af51",
    "pass" : "e4e088f4eaa96db85e11ba491a189f96f2e11793"
}
```

This is useless for the thief, but you can easily compare those values with your precomputed hash in the database. You can run

```
select id from Users where HashedLogin = 'login_from_your_ajax_call' and HashedPassword = 'pass_from_your_ajax_call';
```

If you get any result of this query, your secured verification is completed and you have the Id of a user. If there are no results, the login or password is invalid.

SHA1 is quite secure for home and semi-pro reasons, to compute a hash that will collide your password, you may need up to `2^61` comparisons. It would take literally YEARS for a home computer to break that. This solution is still vulnerable to the man-in-the-middle attacks, but is a leap of security from sending plaintext authentication data.

Also, REMEMBER that even once the user is authenticated, unless you use SSL, *ALL* the other `(client <-> Web Service)` connection is still insecure and easy to sniff.

Comment: Good try, but the hashed login/pass is far from 'useless to the thief'.  He remembers these for next time, and the SELECT statement will pass him too.

Answer (score 3):

If you've got access to a SHA_1 hash function in the browser/phone, about the best you can do is:

1. server sends a (random) 'challenge text' to the browser
2. browser performs some pre-determined modification involving bits from the key, and sends that to the hash function, and the 'response text' to the server
3. server performs the same pre-determined modification involving bits from the key (which it must necessarily store as plain-text, under this scheme), also sends this to the hash function, and compares its result with the result given by the browser
4. *if the browser-supplied and server-supplied hashes **match***, then clearly, the client knows the same key as the server, so assign the session (use a Cookie, like the rest of the world does), and let them in.

This scheme does have some downsides, notably:

- having to keep un-hashed passwords on the server's database (only really a problem if your client re-uses the password elsewhere)
- using the low-entropy password *as* they key weakens the cryptographic strength of the encryption (only really a problem if your determined man on the middle is cryptographically savvy)
- your server might run out of randomness pretty quick, generating the challenge texts, if it must service a lot of logins

If you elect not to use the password itself as the key, then you are down to public-key crypto.  SSL is a strong, convenient and widely-available public-key crypto-system.  It can be quite cheap - some CA's will give you a domain-validated certificate for free.  At this point, you've ask yourself what you are hoping to gain by *not* using the browser-supplied public-key crypto-system.  Any dearth of public-key crypto libraries for Javascript probably reflect this very question in the minds of most people qualified to write one.

Comment: +1 for mentioning session key, something that I skipped in my answer. But still, I think it would be unwise to store plaintext password - unfortunately users (especially the non-advanced ones) tend to use the same password (or variations of one password) in many services.

Comment: @Kamil you are right - it would be discourteous to the users to fail to store salted-and-hashed passwords.  Public-key crypto is the real solution here, as practically everyone has said.  The OP needs to decide the level of risk he is willing to accept on behalf of his users (to treat their passwords in trust-worthy fashion) and on his own behalf (to prevent fraudulent use of protected services).  Your solution favours the confidentiality of users' credentials at the expense of increased risk of fraud.  Mine battens down on fraud, but could put users at increased risk.

Answer (score 2):

One approach would be to have an SSO like mechanism.

- So you have a separate domain/website say www.myOwnSSO.net that
  autheticates users of **ALL** your mobile applications and others.

  1. This www.myOwnSSO.net will issue a token and redirect to your unsecured site.
  2. Your site will send this token to client on first successful login attempt.
  3. For every subsequent call to your server, the client will include this token in request header.
  4. From your server, first thing you do is, ask myOwnSSO to check token expiry.
  5. If token is still valid, you process the request.
  6. If token is expired, you redirect mobile client to log in page. and start with point 2 above.
  7. If token is not valid (i.e. may be some request forgery), you take appropriate measures.

The benefit of this is, the cost of SSL is justified, as it is for all applications; and at the same time, your not so sensitive application is not on https/SSL.

Comment: The OAUTH protocol is targeted at exactly this scenario.  You need not even have to build/operate myownsso.net - it could be Google or another provider.  It's designed to make life easier on the Internet population and on application authors.  I'm not so sure that it would cope with issuing tokens 'in the clear' however.  It's not a dodge for needing an SSL certificate.

Comment: @DavidBullock Agreed for OAUTH protocol. If that is an option can be used.
However, Liath needs **SSL only for Authentication data** and not for real application as clearly stated by him in question, application does not have any sensitive data.

Comment: Your answer is a good one (there, I upvoted it now) - the pointer to OAUTH was merely a little extra hint to the OP that this good approach of yours might be achieved with very little work, and it would be worth looking at the existing options.  I don't know if real-world OAUTH infrastructures would require the use of SSL or not, for transmission of the session-key to the app.  It is logically conceivable, and could be common in practice for all I know, but I would find it surprising.  I don't really understand OP's reluctance to use a real SSL cert, and he didn't choose to elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

If the data is not particularly sensitive then don't invent a bicycle and use SSL with [self signed certificate](http://www.sslshopper.com/article-how-to-create-and-install-an-apache-self-signed-certificate.html). Probably, the simplest authentication method for a webservice is [Basic access authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication). Send username and password with every request over SSL and have no troubles. Send it back from the server to the client on successful login and store the user credentials on the client side in a [local storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp).